# Different widths with Entries and Buttons at tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I´m trying to generate a nice looking pw-generator but i have some issues with the output.

This is the Code but in the Output the buttons and Entries begin at a different point and  it looks not very nice. How can I fix this issue?

```
from tkinter import *

# Entries
website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)

password_entry = Entry(width=20)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

# Buttons
generate_pw_button = Button(text="Generate Password", width=15)
generate_pw_button.grid(column=2, row=3)

add_button = Button(text="Add", width=35)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooyvp.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use different links for images. Paste the image here

Comment: Try adding `sticky="ew"` to all `.grid()`.

Comment: It works, looks pretty much like the image. Try experimenting with `row, column, sticky` values. The thing is it doesn't actually do anything. Do you know how to connect `Entry` objects to `StringVar` or `Buttons` to functions?

Comment: It works with sticky="ew", thx. But why don't they fit if I define a width of 35 for an object and a columnspan of 2 and under this object two objects with a span of 15 and 20. Why don't they align nicely in one line?

Comment: Edit the post to say it's solved

Comment: tkinter will do most of the work for you but you are micro managing everything. I don't know what layout you're looking for but a few small changes can make it more symmetric. I'll post something as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I just set all columns to 0 and gave each object it's own row and used `sticky`.

Also using wildcards for `tkinter` is not good practice.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Entries
website_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
website_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)

email_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
email_entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)

password_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
password_entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)

# Buttons
generate_pw_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate Password", bd = 1, width = 30)
generate_pw_button.grid(column=0, row=3)

add_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add", bd = 1, width = 30)
add_button.grid(column=0, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My goals is a logo at column, row 1,0; 3 labels at 0,1; 01,2, and 0,3 beside them the 3 Entries at 1,1; with a span of 2 1;2 with a span of 2 and 1;3 beside the 1,3 i want a "generate Password button at 2,3 and at the bottom the "add" button at 1,4 with a span of 2.  Everything is fine but the objects are not in line like you can see it in the picture i took under the code section

Comment: I kept the `columnspan` in place, I figured you wanted the buttons side by side or something similar. Just change both `Button` widths to 15 and row of add_button to 3